# Change Background Color of HTML Text Input Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was wondering if it is possible to change the background color of a specific character within the HTML text input element (textbox).
I'm writing a javaScript (jQuery) validator that checks for an array of escape characters. It's a Jquery on 'blur' function. 
My goal is to change the background of the illegal character entered by the user within the textbox itself (6 lines down from the start of the outter-loop). I know you can change the background color of the whole text box but I simply want to target the illegal character(s) within the textbox.

Is this possible? Thanks, Alex

```
$('#contactInfoTable tr td input').on('blur', function() {

    var illegalCharactersPattern = ["@","!","#","%","&",".","*","+","?","^","$","{","}","(",")","|","]","\",","[","/"];
    var inputArray = this.value.split("");

    var illegalCharactersEntered = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {

        for(var j = 0; j < illegalCharactersPattern.length; j++){

            if(inputArray[i] == illegalCharactersPattern[j]){

                $(this.charAt(i)).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
                break;

            } else {
                this.style.backgroundColor = 'inherit';
            } 

        }

    }

} ) ;
```

Comment: Can you post a http://fiddle.net?

Comment: This kind of highlight isn't made in an input but in a editable div, actually.

Comment: What about selecting the offending character and then changing the selected text?

Comment: The short answer is no, this isn't possible. The longer answer would be possibly, using a bit of trickery involving character widths and `linear-gradient`.

Comment: This is my pet project so I'm not opposed to research and more hours of trial. Shaggy, would you mind elaborating a little bit?

Comment: I actually really want to give this a shot to see if it is possible but, unfortunately, I'm running out the door. Will favourite it and see what I can come up with tomorrow (GMT), if it hasn't been answered already.

Comment: @AlexPlouff as mentioned, short answer no. I did a quick test and confirms this. What you'll need to do is build a separate box where the user interacts with where you can control the style. Such as these tag it libraries http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

Comment: What confuses me is that we're allowed to change the background color of the whole textbox but  targeting a specific character's background color is not 'recognized' for lack of a better word.

Comment: I dont think it can be done in textbox. You can use editable div and when ever you encounter an invalid character insert that character inside the span append that span to div innerHTML. Style your span with the required css.